# Problema al posicionar un menú desplegable con css

Tags: css

Hola amigos he intentado posicionar un elemento desplegable (del 2 a 3) a la derecha con "left" y "top", la cosa funciona bien pero el problema radica que si el tamaño del elemento 1 cambia el bloque se desfigura posicionando mal quedando un espacio entre el 1 y el 3.

No se como se puede solucionar ya me ha causado un error de cabeza, el left y top podría llegar a funcionar pero si llega el bloque 1 a cambiar su ancho ya no funcionaria el top y left

[image: Menú]

Código css:

```
/*Menus*/
#container a{
    color: #fff;
}
#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
#container nav{
    margin: 0px 0;
    background-color: #0f131f;
}
#container nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
#container nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #0f131f;
}
#container nav a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#container nav a:hover{
    background-color: #5f5c5c;
}
#container nav ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#container nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#container nav ul ul li{
    width: 100%;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
**Este es el bloque que intento posicionar a la derecha (del 2 a 3) como en imagen**
#container  nav ul ul ul li { 
    position: relative;
}
#container li > a:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: " \f107";
}
#container li > a:only-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Esperando que me puedan ayudar, Saludos Amigos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que describís en la imagen, necesitás declarar en el `ul` un `position: absolute` y `top: 0`. De esta manera, se superpondrá al `li` que está desplegando este menú.

Como no queremos que se superponga y necesitamos mostrarlo a su derecha, declarás un `left:100%`. Lo que esto hace es tomar el ancho del `li` padre y usarlo como una especie de `margin-left`.

De todos modos acá te dejo el código.

```css
#container nav ul li ul li ul {
    position: absolute;

    /* al tener un position absolute, el top 0 hará que
    el ul se superponga al li padre */
    top: 0;

    /* con el left al 100%, se toma el ancho del li padre
    y podríamos decir que actua de margin-left,
    evitando la superposición antes mencionada */
    left: 100%;
    
    /* el ancho del li establecido en max-content para que
    el contenido encaje según el texto que tenga */
    width: max-content;
}
```

El `position: absolute` ya lo tenías declarado, pero de todos modos te lo dejo ahí como para que sea explícito.

Comment: Comento que has colocado el código dentro de un _snippet_ (fragmento de código) y este está diseñado para que se ejecute en el navegador y se pueda comprobar su funcionamiento (como parte de una respuesta o de una pregunta). Pero tu código, al solo ser CSS, no produce ningún resultado al darle _ejecutar_, y por tanto, debiera estar publicado solo como código. He editado la respuesta para que quede de esta manera.